# Proving $\,a\mid b^2\mid a^3\mid b^4\mid a^5\ldots\implies a=b$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704048/theory-number-problems
After I saw that post i wanted to solve the first one which is
$a\mid b^2,b^2\mid a^3,a^3\mid b^4,b^4\mid a^5\cdots$ Prove that $a=b$

Now i started by proving that $a$ and $b$ have same prime divisors,proving that is trivial,after doing so I checked do those factors have to have the same power.I tried with
$$a=p^2,b=p^3$$
I noticed it exactly goes for 3 terms,or that $a^3\mid b^4$
doing $$a=p^{n-1},b=p^n\\p^{n-1}\mid p^{2n}\\p^{2n}\mid p^{3n-3}\\p^{3n-3}\mid p^{4n}\\p^{4n}\mid p^{5n-5}\\\cdots\\p^{n(n-1)}\mid p^{n(n-1)}\\p^{n(n-1)}\mid p^{n(n+1)}\\p^{n(n+1)}\not\mid p^{(n-1)(n+1)}$$
Now yeah I guess that would be a proof,but wouldn't setting $n=n+1$ infinitely many times make every term dividable?

Comment: For every prime that divides $\;a\;$, look at the maximal power of it that still divides it and show the same power divides $\;b\;$...and the other way around, of course.

Comment: What does "setting $n=n+1$ infinitely many times" mean?

Comment: See these questions: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143562/let-a-b-be-positive-integers-such-that-a-mid-b2-b2-mid-a3-a3-mid-b4?lq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281226/given-positive-integers-a-and-b-such-that-a-mid-b2-b2-mid-a3-a3-mid-b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ b(b/a),\,b(b/a)^3,b(b/a)^5\ldots\,$ are *all* integers, i.e. $\,b\,$ is a *common* denominator for $\rm\color{#c00}{unbounded}$ powers of $\,b/a,\,$ so $\,b/a,$ is an integer (*prove* it!), thus $\,a\mid b.\,$  Similarly $\,b\mid a.\,$

**Hint $2\!:$** $\ $ Let $\, r = \frac{b}a = \frac{c}d,\ \color{#0a0}{(c,d)=1}.\,$ Then $\,b\:\!r^k = n_k\in\Bbb Z\,\Rightarrow\, b\:\!c^k = n_k d^k\,$ hence we infer by $\rm\color{#0a0}{Euclid}$: $\,d^k\mid b c^k\Rightarrow\, d^k\mid b^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!$  for $\,\rm\color{#c00}{unbounded}$ $\,k\,$ so $\,d=\pm1,\,$ so $\,r = \frac{c}d = \pm c\in\Bbb Z,\,$ so $\,a\mid b$.

**Remark** $ $ That unbounded powers of proper fractions have no common denominator (such as $b$ above), is a special property of $\,\Bbb Z\,$ that needn't be true in general domains. When it holds true, a domain is called *completely integrally closed*.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/142786/242) for a generalization to Noetherian integrally closed domains, e.g. PIDs.

Comment: “$b$ is a common denominator for unbounded powers of $b/a$, so $b/a$, is an integer.” What does unbounded power mean?

Comment: @Mayank Unbounded powers of $r$ means $\,r^{k_1},\,r^{k_2},\ldots $ for an unbounded sequence of integers $\,k_i.\ $ In the OP it is the sequence of all *odd* powers $\,r, r^3, r^5,\,\ldots\ \ $

Comment: Can you recommend some books for this particular concept? I haven't studied it till now.

Comment: @Mayank Which concept?

Comment: Unbounded powers. I need some more information about it.

Comment: @Mayank It's just a set of powers of $r$ whose exponents are not bounded, e.g. all odd powes of $r$. The point is that denominators $d$ in this sequence will also be unbounded, so they can't all divide the integer $b$ as in the proof.

Comment: I don't get what “not bounded”,“unbounded”,“bounded” mean?

Comment: @Mayank A sequence of integers $\,k_i\,$ is unbounded if it has no upper bound, i.e. there is no integer $\,m\,$ such that all $\,k_i < m\ \ $

Comment: Ok, I got it . Thanks a lot @Bill Dubuque

Comment: A very classic approach

Answer (score 2):

Let $\nu_p(n)$ be the $p$-adic valuation of $n$ for a prime $p$.

Note for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have
$(2n+1) \nu_p(a) \leq (2n+2) \nu_p(b)$ and
$(2n+2) \nu_p(b) \leq (2n+3) \nu_p(a)$ so that
$$1 - \frac{1}{2n+3} = \frac{2n+2}{2n+3} \leq \frac{\nu_p(a)}{\nu_p(b)} \leq \frac{2n+2}{2n+1} = 1+ \frac{1}{2n+1}.$$
As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{2n+3} \to 0$ and $\frac{1}{2n+1} \to 0$, so $\frac{\nu_p(a)}{\nu_p(b)} \to 1$ and $\nu_p(a) = \nu_p(b)$ for each $p$. Thus, $a = b$ as desired.