# Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 , a^3\mid b^4 \ldots$ so on , then $a=b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 , a^3\mid b^4 \ldots$ that is $a^{2n-1}\mid b^{2n} ; b^{2n}\mid a^{2n+1} , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+$ , then is it true that $a=b$ ?

Comment: If $a \neq b$ then there can be 2 options - either there is an uncommon prime divisor, or there is only a difference in prime powers.
Think about what this means for the powers of prime divisors...

Comment: This might be useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704135/number-theory-why-is-my-approach-incorrect

Comment: @mousomer : off-course I can clearly see that $a,b$ has same set of prime divisors , so only difference is in powers of those primes

Comment: So it's really a question of simple arithmetic. If the powers are $x$ and $y$ then what this amounts to is $2ny-y \le 2nx \le 2ny+y$

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704048/theory-number-problems)

Comment: See a recent duplicate with answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1281226/given-positive-integers-a-and-b-such-that-a-mid-b2-b2-mid-a3-a3-mid-b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a <b$ then $$\lim_n\frac{b^{2n}}{a^{2n+1}}= \infty$$

which means that from some point $b^{2n} >a^{2n+1}$, and it cannot divide it.

Same way, if $a>b$ then

$$\lim_n\frac{a^{2n-1}}{b^{2n}}= \infty$$

Comment: Who or what are those two "it" 's in your "...and *it* cannot divide *it*"?

Comment: @Timbuc If $b^{2n} >a^{2n+1}$ then $b^{2n}$ cannot divide $a^{2n+1}$... note that $a$ cannot be $0$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $p$ a prime that divides $a$ then since $a|b^2$ then $p$ divides $b$. Similarly we get that if $p$ is a prime that divides $b$ then it divides $a$ hence $a$ and $b$ has the same primes in their primary decomposition. Now if $p^\alpha$ is the factor of the primary decomposition of $a$ and $p^\beta$ is that of $b$ then

$$\alpha\le2\beta\le3\alpha\le 4\beta\le\cdots$$ then

$$\alpha\le\frac {2n}{2n-1}\beta,\quad \forall n$$
and
$$\beta \le\frac {2n+1}{2n}\alpha,\quad \forall n$$
so by taking the limit $n\to\infty$ we get $\alpha=\beta$ and then $a=b$.

Comment: $n$ must be even.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane : It should be : $\alpha \le \dfrac {2n}{2n-1} \beta ; \beta \le \dfrac {2n+1}{2n} \alpha , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+$

Answer (score 3):

This is a twist of another answer here in order to avoid prime factorization.

We may assume $a,b>1$. Then
$$\frac{2n-1}{2n} \leq \frac{\log b}{\log a} \leq \frac{2n+1}{2n}$$
for all $n$. Taking $n \to \infty$, we get $a=b$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the given condition, it is clear that the prime factors of $a$ and $b$ are the same. 
Without loss of generality, you can assume that $a = p^i$ and $b=p^j$ where $p$ is a prime factor and $i,j\in \mathbb N$ (for if $a_k$ and $b_k$ are of this form and fulfill the given condition, it is clear that $a$ = product of $a_k$ and $b$ = product of $b_k$ fulfills this condition too, and conversely etc.).
There holds $p^i|p^{2j}$, $p^{2j}|p^{3i}$ etc. 
Hence $i \leq  2j \leq 3i \leq 4j \cdots \leq n i \leq (n+1) j\leq (n+2) i$ etc. Taking $n$ large shows that $i=j$.

In conclusion, yes $a = b$.

Comment: $n$ must be odd.

Comment: the parity of $n$ has nothing to do with this : ${n\over n+1}i\leq j \leq {n+1\over n+2}i$

Comment: The problem says it is odd. Whether it is true when it is not odd is a different matter and you never proved it.