# Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 , a^3\mid b^4 \ldots$.....so on, then prove that $a=b$ -Struck

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

**QUESTION :**

> Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 , a^3\mid b^4 \ldots$.....so on, then prove that $a=b$

This is what I tried:

Say $a≠b$ rather than $a>b≥1$

$$\exists k :a^{k-1}>b^k$$
Then:
$$a^{k-1}>b^k$$
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^k>a$$
$$k>\log_{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)}a$$
I am struck after this. I don't
know what to do next (even I don't know what I have done is right or wrong).

What to do next?

---

I apologise for asking a same question which exist [already on S.E.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143562/let-a-b-be-positive-integers-such-that-a-mid-b2-b2-mid-a3-a3-mid-b4) but I didn't understand that(due to limit).

Comment: If you don't understand some prior answers then please first ask for elaboration there before posting duplicate questions. If you receive no (sufficient) reply there then ask a more specific question on the point in the proof that was not clear (not the whole problem).

Comment: A *conceptual* way to view this *number theoretically* it to employ the unboundedness of the denominators of powers of proper fractions, i.e. if a common denominator exists for a sequence of unbounded powers of a fraction [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/893105/242) the fraction is integer. So here $\,b(b/a),\,b(b/a)^3,b(b/a)^5\ldots\,$ are all integers, so $\,b\,$ is a common denom for all odd powers of $\,b/a\,$ so $\,b/a\in\Bbb Z\,$ so $\,a\mid b.\,$ Similarly $\,b\mid a\,$ so $\,a = \pm b.\ \ \ $

Comment: If you chase all the "Linked" questions in the linked dupes you will find many answers at various levels of detail, including generalizations

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I wanted to know, what I have done is right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is fine. You have shown that for $k > \log_{\frac ab}a$ (which is some constant), we will have:

$$a^{k-1}>b^k$$

For this (possibly very large) $k$, we cannot write down
$$a^{k-1} \mid b^k$$

since a divisor of a positive integer cannot exceed that integer.

You have shown what they have done with limits by giving a concrete bound.

Comment: Since we cannot write down $a^{k-1}\mid b^k$, we have reached a contradiction. This contradiction arises from our initial assumption $a>b\ge 1$, so this assumption must be wrong.

Comment: Conclusion: $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

This follows in a finite number of the division statements, if you use the prime factorization of both.  If a prime divides one of them (the exponent of the prime is nonzero) then it divides the other, just from the first two statements

$$a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 .$$
Now let $m,n \geq 1$ be integers, the exponents in the prime factorizations,
$$   a = p^m \cdot \mbox{OTHER_A} $$
$$   b = p^n \cdot \mbox{OTHER_B} $$

> Let $a,b$ be positive integers such that $a\mid b^2 , b^2\mid a^3 , a^3\mid b^4 \ldots$.....so on, then prove that $a=b$

For this prime $p$, the first few "divides"  statements read

$$  m \leq 2n \; , \;  $$
$$  2n \leq 3m \; , \;  $$

$$  3m \leq 4n \; , \;  $$
$$  4n \leq 5m \; , \;  $$

For any positive odd number $c$ we have the pair
$$  cm \leq (1+c) n \; , \; $$

Take $c > n$  so that $$ \frac{n}{c} < 1. $$
$$  m \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{c} \right) n = n + \frac{n}{c} < n+1.   $$
Put together, $m < n+1$  and
$$ m \leq n \; .  $$

For even positive integer $d$
$$  d n \leq (1+d) m \; . \; $$
Take $d > m$  so that $$ \frac{m}{d} < 1. $$
$$  n \leq \left(1 + \frac{1}{d} \right) m = m + \frac{m}{d} < m+1.   $$
Put together, $n < m+1$  and
$$ n \leq m \; .  $$

As $n \leq m$  and $m \leq n,$   we have
$$  m=n $$

These were exponents of some prime $p$ that divides your two numbers. The argument applies to every prime that divides at least one of the numbers: the exponents are equal. Therefore $a=b.$