# $a|b^2$ , $b^2|a^3$ , $a^3|b^4$ , $b^4| a^5$... then...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive interger such that $a|b^2$ , $b^2|a^3$ , $a^3|b^4$ , $b^4| a^5$ ... Prove that $a=b$.

Here how I tried to do it, I think it isn't the best way to approach it but anyway I failed in proving it:

EDIT: Let $a = p_1 ^{a_1} p_2 ^{a_2}  ... p_k ^{a_k}$ and $b=  p_1 ^{b_1} p_2 ^{b_2}  ... p_k ^{b_k}$ and $a_i, b_i \geq 0$ for $i$, $ 0 \leq i \leq k$. Then for a specific prime $p_i$, $a_i \leq 2b_i$, $2b_i \leq 3a_i$ , $3a_i \leq 4b_i$ and $4b_i \leq  5a_i$.... I tried to get some information from that but didn't get anything.

This question has been marked as a duplicate but it is in fact different, or maybe that's what I can directly deduce from the conditions. Just look carefully at the titles to realise that they are different.

Comment: You don't get $a_i\mid 2b_i$ etc, but $a_i \le 2b_i$ etc.

Comment: @Vmimi Though the exponent sequence differs slightly, the same methods in the linked dupe work here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right, I think I was just focused on division

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry I edited it before seeing your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @BillDubuque Wouldn't [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310140/if-a-b-are-positive-integers-such-that-ab2-b2a3-then-a-b) be a better duplicate?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Yes, but I can't reopen and reclose. But it matters little since - as I said above -  the method of solution is exactly the same for both.

Comment: @BillDubuque Oh I thought the gold badge allowed you to do that, or maybe modify the "duplicate" notice somehow. But as you say, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @ArnaudD. You can't close twice. In any case, the question is surely a dupe (and will likely be soon deleted) so there's little point to polish the dupe target.

Comment: The title and the question doesn't match.  Does the sequence stop at $b^4\mid a^5$ or does it go on forever?